# Оптимизация кода (избежать if else)

Tags: java, оптимизация

У меня имеется определённое количество методов, сигнатуры которых отличаются только второй частью названия. Я вызываю эти методы в зависимости от значения в *String* переменной, проверяя её значение *if else*. Возможно ли как-то оптимизировать код таким образом, чтобы убрать огромное количество *if else*? (использовать *switch* - плохой ответ)

```java
void main() {
    String s = getFomDataBase();

    if (s.equals("A")) doA();
    else if (s.equals("B")) doB();
    else if (s.equals("C")) doC();
    else if (s.equals("D")) doD();
}

void doA() {};
void doB() {};
void doC() {};
void doD() {};
```

Comment: в данном конкретном случае можно еще рефлексионно вызывать методы, поскольку ваши String совпадает с названием вызываемого метода

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы можете заменить if-else на switch-case

```
    switch (s) {
        case "A":
            doA();
            break;
        case "B":
            doB();
            break;
        case "C":
            doC();
            break;
        case "D":
            doD();
            break;
    }
```

ну или заменить на HashMap, если это вам больше подойдет

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<String, Runnable> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("A", Application::doA);
    map.put("B", Application::doB);
    map.put("C", Application::doC);
    map.put("D", Application::doD);

    // .......

    String s = "A";
    if (map.containsKey(s)) map.get(s).run();
}

static void doA() {};
static void doB() {};
static void doC() {};
static void doD() {};
```

Comment: А возможно ли при использовании варианта с HashMap передавать параметры в методы?

Comment: Возможно, но тогда вам придется использовать другой функциональный интерфейс вместо `Runnable`

Comment: Поделитесь секретом, какой?

Comment: так это зависит от вашего параметра

Comment: Предположим, что у меня везде параметр String. Что следует использовать в таком случае?

Comment: [Choosing a Functional Interface](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2171751&seqNum=3). Если вы хотите передать один параметр, и не возвращать ничего, то наверное `Consumer<T>`

Comment: Ок, спасибо за помощь.

Comment: проблема в том, что `s` это какая-то строка, т.е. один и тот же тип объекта, отсюда и непонятно зачем столько методов.. укрупните свое изобретение, тогда будет возвращаться `ObjectA, ObjectB` и т.д. эти объекты могут происходить от одного родителя `ObjectXXX`, который будет иметь интерфейс единственным методом `do()`, и каждый класс `ObjectA, ObjectB `и т.д. будет иметь собственную реализацию этого метода, таким образом, `else if` умрет на корню, потому что код упростится до вида `ObjectXXX  s = getFomDataBase(); s.do();`

Comment: @keekkenen как будет выглядеть метод `getFomDataBase()` в таком случае? Что у него внутри будет написано? Учитывая, что в БД хранится только строка.

Comment: @tym32167, в базах просто строки не хранят, строка это атрибут какого объекта - сущности

Comment: @keekkenen ок, как будет выглядеть метод getFomDataBase() в таком случае? Что у него внутри будет написано? Учитывая, что в БД хранится одна таблица с записями.

Comment: как ранее писал, следует изменить свое представление.. иначе, если это строка, то должно быть достаточно использовать класса `String` для манипуляции с данными.. в противном случае, каждая запись в таблице это отдельная сущность (даже если она состоит из одного описательного поля, ну и еще уникальный идентификатор, иначе как ей жить в таблице), для описания которой есть отдельный класс, для получения сущности есть отдельный сервис, вот в нем и должен быть такой метод

Comment: @keekkenen я вам пытаюсь пояснить, что это все рпавно приведет к коду типа в ответе в том или ином виде

Comment: все зависит от желания писать `SOLID`ный код, но да, `божественный класс` звучит лучше

Comment: @keekkenen я не понимаю о чем вы говорите и причем тут SOLID, потому попросил с вас пример кода. Можете его привести?